# Get the result inside an object is coming from ajax using getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, getjson

Guys I try access and save the data is coming from ajax using getJson I have some like this

```
var conversation

conversation = $.getJSON("http://myapi&jsonp=?", function (response) {
                return response;
        });

    console.log(conversation)
```

I get in my console this

[image]

I getting my data inside of responseJSON  so I try do some like this

```
conversation.responseJSON.DATA
```

but this is give to me undefined what am I doing wrong ? can some one help me pleases

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is an asynchronous call, that means that it doesn't get the results instantly, it make a call to the server and the results are available to the the callback function.

You need to put all the code that accesses the results returned from the server inside your callback function

```
function (response) {
    // this is where your code goes.
}
```

In your code above the variable conversation is a promise, you don't get the results from the promise but with the callback function that runs when the promise resolves.

The usual way of access a promise is with a then call.

```
var conversationPromise = $.getJSON("http://myapi&jsonp=?");

conversationPromise.then(function(results) {
  // Here is where your results are available.
});
```